# Twisted Spread: How to authenticate each RPC with digital signature

Tags: python, twisted, rpc, digital-signature

I have remote objects which talk each others with RPCs, using Twisted Spread.

I want that objects authenticate messages, before using them, with digital signatures, but I don't know where to start to implement this.

In my head, the Root object must have a public/private key pair, and the Client too. When a message is sent, a digital signature of the hash is added, and when it is received, the signature is checked. Is the Protocol part where I need to add these adds and checks?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered just using TLS and authenticating the connection rather than individual messages?

Comment: It's a solution, but I want to use UDP as transport layer.

Comment: TLS supports UDP.  It's called DTLS.  However, you cannot use Spread over UDP.  Also UDP is an optimization to explore after you've finished developing your application and it satisfies all requirements and is relatively unbuggy but you find that it does meet performance requirements and you track down the bottleneck to TCP-induced latency.  It's basically always wrong to try to use UDP before that point.

Comment: I'm writing a kademlia implementation, and the paper specifies UDP as transport layer.

Comment: It doesn't specify Spread, but you're using that.  So you can use TCP, too.  Alternatively, if you are trying to implement the specification exactly (necessary if you want any interop with other implementations), then you can't use Twisted Spread.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. And I have read elsewhere that porting Spread to UDP is useless, so I'll implement my own RPC infrastructure with digital signatures.